# Implementation of user permissions

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, permissions

I am building a web-application in NodeJS (using TypeScript) and MongoDB (using mongoose).

In my application I have 6 types of permissions. 
For the simplicity, lets use P1, P2, ..., P6 to represent my permissions.

In addition, the application has several organizations.

Each user in the application belongs to one organization and can have several permissions (P1-P6) for each organization (not necessarily the one he belongs to).

For example:

- User 'U1' belongs to 'O1' organization, has permissions P1, P3 in organization 'O1' and permissions
  P2,P6 in organization 'O2'.
- User 'U2' belongs to 'O2' organization, has permission P1 in organization 'O2'.
- User 'U3' belongs to 'O1' organization, has no permissions.

I am trying to implement this structure in the user schema (using mongoose schema) and need some opinions about my implementations.

This is my user schema:

```
var userSchema: mongoose.Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: {
        type: String
    },
    firstName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    lastName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    mail: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    organization: { // User's organization
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Organization'
    },
    permissions: [{
        organization: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Organization'
        }, 
        permissions: [{
            type: String,
            enum: [
                Permission.P1,
                Permission.P2,
                Permission.P3,
                Permission.P4,
                Permission.P5,
                Permission.P6,
            ]
        }]
    }]
});
```

For the permissions enum I use :

```
export enum Permission {
    P1 = <any>'P1',
    P2 = <any>'P2',
    P3 = <any>'P3',
    P4 = <any>'P4',
    P5 = <any>'P5',
    P6 = <any>'P6',
}
```

I use this enum as string values because I think it's better to have the string value of the permission and not just the enum number values (1-6).
Of course the permission names (P1-P6) are replaced with the real permission name - for example P1 is Administrator.

I am not sure about my current implementation and would like to get some opinions whether I am doing good or should I change something.

Please feel free to criticize my code and way of thinking.

Thanks,

Ron.

Answer (score 1):

You probably will be interested in [CASL](https://stalniy.github.io/casl/) . You can read about its integration in Expressjs + mongoose app:

https://medium.com/@sergiy.stotskiy/authorization-with-casl-in-express-app-d94eb2e2b73b

Answer (score 0):

You can also just add the role directly on your userSchema. So something like this? Unless each organization is going to customize their permissions?

`var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: {
        type: String
    },
    firstName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    lastName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    mail: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    organization: { // User's organization
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Organization'
    },
    admin       :{type:Boolean},
    superAdmin  :{type:Boolean},
    globalAdmin :{type:Boolean}
})`

Comment: Each organization can change permissions to its users, so this method not really suits me...